# Git get specific version

Tags: git

I am trying to get specific version in git and commit it as the current version. Consider this example scenario:

```
tag : v2 (current version)
files : 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt

tag : v1
files : 55.xml,33.yml
```

I am trying to switch to tag v1 and make it as my current version (get this specific version)

By searching web, i could able to find out way to get all the files

```
git checkout tag_name
# ex. git checkout v1
```

And this actually fetches the files from the specific version and loads into my working directory.

But i cannot commit the existing files and push it back to server.

(When it try to push, it shows like no changes pending)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows no changes pending because there are no changes.  If you want `master` on the remote to point to `v1`, you can do an `update-ref` or a `reset` on the remote.  If you want to create a new commit which is a child of `v2` that has the same tree as `v1`, you could do a `merge`.  What exactly is it that you want to do?  Is the remote a bare repo, or is it a working directory?  If the former, you should do nothing and anyone who wants to see the files at `v1` should checkout `v1`.  If the latter, you should simply checkout `v1` on the remote but make no new commits.

From your comments, it sounds like you want to make a new commit to the remote repo which has the same file content as the tag `v1`.  It really is best to simply use `update-ref` on the remote repo to reset it back to `v1`, but it is certainly possible to make a new commit.  One approach is:

```
git reset $( echo 'Resetting repo to v1' | git commit-tree $(
    git show -s --format='%T' v1 ) -p v2 )
```

This computes the tree of `v1`, invokes commit-tree with that argument to create a new commit object whose parent is `v2` (or use HEAD, or whatever you want to be the parent of the new commit) using the commit log "Resetting repo to v1" and then resets the repo so that HEAD points to the new commit.   After doing this, you should be able to push to the repo.  It might be simpler to just do a `pull` and merge in the old tree, but that may require a fair bit of manual intervention resolving conflicts.

Comment: As shown in the question, right now my files are 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt.
But the expected result is, after doing this get specific version
the files should be 55.xml,33.yml. And this should be the current one,
when some user pulls this project after i did a get specific version.

Their project folder should be loaded with only files 55.xml,33.yml

Comment: Please let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: If someone pulls from your repo, that is what they will get.  But you haven't answered my question.  Is your remote repo bare?  If so, use `update-ref`.  If not, just checkout `v1` on the remote.  Why do you want to make a new commit?

Comment: No the repo is secured (only can be accessed by us)
Actually checking out will give me the files 55.xml,33.yml in my folder. But i want in a way so that after i do this specific version any user who does git clone(git pull) should only have these files 55.xml,33.yml get copied to the project folder..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tags, you should checkout the tag into a branch.

```
git checkout -b v2 branch_v2
```

This will checkout your project's state at tag v2 into a branch called branch_v2 (you can call it whatever you want).

Comment: the version i am trying to get is v1.4
when i typed `git checkout v1.4 branch_v1` it shows like error: pathspec 'branch_v1' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - I forgot the -b flag. see the amended answer.

Comment: i tried this `git checkout -b v1.4 branch_v1`, but it shows like `fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'branch_v1' which can not be resolved as commit?`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get a specific revision:

```
$ git fetch origin cd379d1c02ae095ad945c8c8c833f4fa2aaf51a7
$ git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Then if I want to do some work and add commits from there from the tag you just checked out, I would create a new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b v1a
$ git push -u origin v1a
```